# Running Ruby on Rails as systemd

Tags: linux, shell, ruby

**OS: Centos 7**

I am trying to run Snorby as systemd but the scripts are not starting correctly

I can do bundle exec rails server -e development -b 0.0.0.0 on the command line while in Snorby folder without any issues but when I put it in a script and execute with systemctl it is not working correctly.

`[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/tmp/snorby
Environment=RAILS_ENV=development
ExecStart=/usr/local/rbenv/shims/bundle exec rails server -d -b 0.0.0.0`

**Status output**

```
snorby.service - Snorby ConfiServ

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snorby.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)

Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-08-03 13:25:34 UTC; 1min 18s ago
  Process: 5533 ExecStart=/usr/local/rbenv/shims/bundle exec rails server -d -b 0.0.0.0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5533 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 03 13:25:32 TEST-02 systemd[1]:   
 Started Snorby ConfiServ.

Aug 03 13:25:32 TEST-02 systemd[1]:  
 Starting Snorby ConfiServ...

Aug 03 13:25:34 TEST-02 bundle[5533]:  
 /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF

Aug 03 13:25:34 TEST-02 bundle[5533]:  
 /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: previous definition of PDF was here  

Aug 03 13:25:34 TEST-02 bundle[5533]:  
  No time_zone specified in snorby_config.yml; detected time_zone: UTC

Aug 03 13:25:34 TEST-02 bundle[5533]: => Booting Thin

Aug 03 13:25:34 TEST-02 bundle[5533]: => Rails 3.2.22 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Answer (score 1):

In My case , it worked when I used 'bash -l' before the script like below.

**ExecStart=/bin/bash -l 'your ruby command or script'**

I guess centos 7 has some problem loading ruby environment variables with systemd. It worked on ubuntu without -l option though.

Answer (score -2):

I figure it out - you need to startup Thin on Systemd

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly with more detail so others understand clearly what you did to resolve.